# Duda sobre enteros y decimales en C++

Tags: c++, c

Cómo hago para que mi código al momento de generar un output en decimales diga que es false y que cuando el output lo genere en enteros diga que es true.
Lo anterior en C++.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo y qué has intentado hasta la fecha?

Comment: ¿al momento de generar un *output*? Pero ¿mostrando el número o mostrando el verdadero/falso o mostrando ambas cosas?

Comment: Debido a que la pregunta es para C++, podrías quitar la etiqueta de C?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes examinar el tipo de datos a imprimir y mostrar un mensaje según si tiene o no tiene decimales. Para examinar las características de un tipo deberás usar la cabecera [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void imprime(const T valor)
{
    std::cout << valor << (std::is_floating_point_v<T> ? " Tiene decimales\n" : " No tiene decimales\n");
}
```

Las siguientes llamadas:

```
imprime(0);
imprime(1./3.);
imprime(10/3);
imprime("Mi mama me mima");
```

Producen la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 0 No tiene decimales
> 0.333333 Tiene decimales
> 3 No tiene decimales
> Mi mama me mima No tiene decimales
> ```

Pero como `"Mi mama me mima"` no es un número, no nos vale, tendremos que evitar que la función acepte valores que no sean numéricos, lo más fácil es usar [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```
template <typename T>
void imprime(const T valor)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Solo numeros por favor");
    std::cout << valor << (std::is_floating_point_v<T> ? " Tiene decimales\n" : " No tiene decimales\n");
}
```

Con este cambio, el código no compila, mostrando el siguiente fallo:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'void imprime(T) [with T = const char*]':
> required from here
> error: static assertion failed: Solo numeros por favor
> static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "Solo numeros por favor");
>               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```